# How to create a credentials in service now

Tags: servicenow

Hi I am new to service now.I have an demo instance "demonowprod.service-now.com" when I try to retrieve data from rest API URL it throws authentication fail message like below.

```
 https://demochannel.service-now.com/api/now/table/incident?sysparm_limit=1

 {
"error": {
"detail": "Required to provide Auth information",
"message": "User Not Authenticated"
},
"status": "failure"
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So you have two or one instances?

At first you say your instance name is `demonowprod.service-now.com` in your query you call `demochannel.service-now.com`.

The credentials used for API calls are your user credentials. Of course you need to have read access on the incident table when querying it.

Comment: 1 instance only.For example purpose I mentioned the URL.I don't have user credentials.How can I create credentials ?

Comment: the credentials are the one you use to login to your instance. If it's your instance you must login somehow, correct?

Comment: Ah I see you are trying to query the demo instance of servicenow. You will have to create your own instance first where you can login as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is create a service account of sorts and assign the "rest_service" role to that account. Use this credential when connecting from the other instance of SN. User accounts are created by either admins or user_admins under User Administration > Users.

See http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=REST_API#gsc.tab=0